# How can i verify the code while using FlutterLogin?

Tags: flutter

I am using flutter_login for my user onboarding functionality. My only problem is that I cannot override the verification code sent to the email section. How can I send the OTP using a custom API call and also verify the same?. Below is my register screen. I would appreciate any leads on the same or an alternative approach to OTP login using google without firebase. Thank you

```
 import 'package:email_validator/email_validator.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart' show timeDilation;
import 'package:flutter_login/flutter_login.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:konnectsoko/managers/app_state_manager.dart';
import 'package:konnectsoko/managers/profile_manager.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../pages/konnectmart_pages.dart';

class RegisterScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static MaterialPage page = MaterialPage(
      name: KonnectmartPages.registerPath,
      key: ValueKey(KonnectmartPages.registerPath),
      child: RegisterScreen());
  static const routeName = '/auth';

  RegisterScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  Duration get loginTime => Duration(milliseconds: timeDilation.ceil() * 1150);

  Future<String?> _loginUser(LoginData data) {
    //add login logic here
    print(data);
    return Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 300));
  }

  Future<String?> _signupUser(SignupData data) {
    //prepare data from the form
    final Map<String, dynamic> userData = {
      'phone': data.name,
      'firstname': data.additionalSignupData!['First Name'],
      'lastname': data.additionalSignupData!['Last Name'],
      'dob': data.additionalSignupData!['Date Of Birth'],
      'gender': data.additionalSignupData!['Gender'],
      'email': data.additionalSignupData!['Email'],
      'password': data.password
    };

    //call api endpoint for reg

    return Future.delayed(loginTime).then((_) {
      return null;
    });
  }

  // Future<String?> _recoverPassword(String name) {
  //   return Future.delayed(loginTime).then((_) {
  //     if (!mockUsers.containsKey(name)) {
  //       return 'User not exists';
  //     }
  //     return null;
  //   });
  // }

  Future<String?> _signupConfirm(String error, SignupData data) {

    return Future.delayed(loginTime).then((_) {
     
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlutterLogin(
      title: 'Konnectmart',
      logo: const AssetImage('image/img2.png'),
      navigateBackAfterRecovery: true,
      onConfirmSignup: (String error, LoginData data) {
        //we have phone
        //invoke otp endpoint here
        //confirm otp

          return Future.delayed(loginTime).then((_) {
            Provider.of<AppStateManager>(context, listen: false).login();
          });


      },
      hideForgotPasswordButton: false,
      loginAfterSignUp: true,
      loginProviders: [
        LoginProvider(
          button: Buttons.Facebook,
          label: 'Sign in with Facebook',
          callback: () async {},
          providerNeedsSignUpCallback: () {
            // put here your logic to conditionally show the additional fields
            return Future.value(true);
          },
        ),
        LoginProvider(
          icon: FontAwesomeIcons.google,
          label: 'Google',
          callback: () async {
            final _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
            await _googleSignIn.signIn();
            print(_googleSignIn.currentUser);
            Provider.of<AppStateManager>(context, listen: false).login();
            Provider.of<ProfileManager>(context, listen: false)
                .showGoogleProfile(_googleSignIn.currentUser);
          },
        ),
      ],

      termsOfService: [
        TermOfService(
            id: 'general-term',
            mandatory: true,
            text: 'Term of services',
            linkUrl: 'https://github.com/Dmaina5054/'),
      ],
      additionalSignupFields: [
        // const UserFormField(
        //     keyName: 'Username', icon: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.userLarge)),
        UserFormField(
          keyName: 'Date Of Birth',
          fieldValidator: (value) {
            //perform date validation here
          },
        ),
        const UserFormField(keyName: 'First Name'),
        const UserFormField(keyName: 'Last Name'),
        UserFormField(keyName: 'Email', fieldValidator: _emailValidator),
        const UserFormField(keyName: 'Gender'),
      ],
      initialAuthMode: AuthMode.signup,
      scrollable: true,
      hideProvidersTitle: false,

      disableCustomPageTransformer: true,

      messages: LoginMessages(
        additionalSignUpFormDescription:
            'Tell us more about you. \n Please fill the details below',
        confirmationCodeHint: 'Enter code sent to your phone',
        userHint: 'Phone',
        passwordHint: 'Password',
        confirmPasswordHint: 'Confirm Password',
        loginButton: 'LOG IN',
        signupButton: 'REGISTER',
        forgotPasswordButton: 'Forgot password?',
        recoverPasswordButton: 'Reset',
        goBackButton: 'GO BACK',
        confirmPasswordError: 'Not match!',
        recoverPasswordIntro: 'Don\'t feel bad. Happens all the time.',
        recoverPasswordDescription: 'Your password will be reset',
        recoverPasswordSuccess: 'Password rescued successfully',
        flushbarTitleError: 'Oh no!',
        flushbarTitleSuccess: 'Succes!',
      ),
     
        buttonTheme: LoginButtonTheme(
          //  splashColor: Colors.blue,
          // backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          highlightColor: Colors.lightGreen,
          elevation: 9.0,
          highlightElevation: 6.0,
          shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      userValidator: (value) {
        var phoneRegExp = RegExp(
            '^(\\+\\d{1,2}\\s)?\\(?\\d{3}\\)?[\\s.-]?\\d{3}[\\s.-]?\\d{4}\$');
        if (value != null && value.length < 9 && !phoneRegExp.hasMatch(value)) {
          return "Please enter a valid phonenumber";
        }
        return null;
      },

      passwordValidator: (value) {
        if (value!.isEmpty) {
          return 'Password is empty';
        }
        return null;
      },
      onLogin: (loginData) {
        debugPrint('Login info');
        debugPrint('Name: ${loginData.name}');
        debugPrint('Password: ${loginData.password}');
        Provider.of<AppStateManager>(context, listen: false).login();

        return _loginUser(loginData);
      },

      onSignup: (signupData) {
        debugPrint('Signup info');
        debugPrint('Name: ${signupData.name}');
        debugPrint('Password: ${signupData.password}');

        signupData.additionalSignupData?.forEach((key, value) {
          debugPrint('$key: $value');
        });
        if (signupData.termsOfService.isNotEmpty) {
          debugPrint('Accept Terms of service: ');
          for (var element in signupData.termsOfService) {
            debugPrint(
                ' - ${element.term.id}: ${element.accepted == true ? 'accepted' : 'rejected'}');
          }
        }

        final Map<String, dynamic> userData = {
          'phone': signupData.name,
          'firstname': signupData.additionalSignupData!['First Name'],
          'lastname': signupData.additionalSignupData!['Last Name'],
          'dob': signupData.additionalSignupData!['Date Of Birth'],
          'gender': signupData.additionalSignupData!['Gender'],
          'email': signupData.additionalSignupData!['Email'],
          'password': signupData.password
        };

        //hit our endpoint
        Provider.of<ProfileManager>(context, listen: false).registerUser(
            firstname: userData['firstname'],
            lastname: userData['lastname'],
            phone: userData['phone'],
            email: userData['email'],
            gender: userData['gender'],
            dob: userData['dob'],
            password: userData['password']);

        return _signupConfirm('noerr',signupData);
      },
      onSubmitAnimationCompleted: () {
        print('completed');
      },

      onRecoverPassword: (name) {
        debugPrint('Recover password info');
        debugPrint('Name: $name');
        return _recoverPassword(name);
        // Show new password dialog
      },
      showDebugButtons: false,
      userType: LoginUserType.phone,
    );
  }

  _recoverPassword(String name) {
    print(name);
  }

  Widget buildDateField(BuildContext context) {
    // 1
    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        // 2
        Row(
          // 3
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            // 4
            Text(
              'Date',
              style: GoogleFonts.lato(fontSize: 28.0),
            ),
            // 5
          ],
        ),
        // 9
      ],
    );
  }

  String? _emailValidator(String? value) {
    if (value!.isEmpty) {
      return 'Email needed';
    } else if (!EmailValidator.validate(value, true)) {
      return 'Enter a valid email';
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: `OTP login using google without firebase` Google is Firebase, how do you want to use Google without Firebase? Please clarify your question.

Comment: Thanks for your question. Found a package called flutter_login that allows a developer to add login and signup functionality to an app. The package has a provider section where one can use Google, Facebook, LinkedIn.

Answer (score 0):

The methods provider either expects a return of null if otp entered by user was correct or a message indicating what failed. I added my verify otp endpoint call and now works as expected.
[image: otp verification failed]